# codeigniter how to connect to a Progress database using ODBC

Tags: database, codeigniter, odbc, progress-db

Im using codeigniter and my php code is sitting on a IIS 5 box.
I need to connect to my database, which is is a linux box, database type is Progress, and it's uding an ODBC driver.

Can someone please help me figure out how the codeigniter database settings should be?
Below is what I have, but it's not working (I get A Database Error Occurred Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.).  By the way. other scripts can connect using this: odbc_connect("DSN=mynameV10","","",SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC)

```
$db['cf']['hostname'] = "1xx.xxx.x.xx"; //some ip address
$db['cf']['username'] = '';
$db['cf']['password'] = '';
$db['cf']['database'] = 'dbname';
$db['cf']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['cf']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['cf']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['cf']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['cf']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['cf']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['cf']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['cf']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['cf']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['cf']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
$db['cf']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['cf']['port'] = 9300;
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there anyone out there that can please help me with this?  I just need to be able to connect to the progress database using codeigniter and odbc method....

Answer (score 0):

Your hostname should be your DSN name not the server IP.  Start with that.